# Rotating script will not rotate

Tags: php

I have a rotator script that shows a different image every time my website is shown. It will not work as some of my background descriptions have an apostrophe in the description. Is there any way to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope I do not need to find another scrips as my script has 1200 pictures but I was only able to put a few in here as there were too many characters.

```html
<?php
//Add as many links you want
$mylink[1] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a beaver dam pond along Portage Road.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A beaver dam pond along Portage Road *
</div>';
$mylink[2] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a beaver dam pond along Portage Road.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A beaver dam pond along Portage Road *
</div>';
$mylink[3] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a farm Middle River.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A farm Middle River *
</div>';
$mylink[4] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a fog bank creeping into Lakies Head, CapeBreton Highlands National Park.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A fog bank creeping into Lakies Head, CapeBreton Highlands National Park *
</div>';
$mylink[5] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a foggy rainy Blacketts Lake.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A foggy rainy Blacketts Lake *
</div>';
$mylink[6] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a moonlit spring waterfall - North Mountain, Cape Breton Highlands National Park.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A moonlit spring waterfall - North Mountain, Cape Breton Highlands National Park *
</div>';
$mylink[7] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a rainbow over Cape Smokey.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A rainbow over Cape Smokey *
</div>';
$mylink[8] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a rock beach near Cap Rouge.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A rock beach near Cap Rouge *
</div>';
$mylink[9] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a rock beach near Whale Cove.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A rock beach near Whale Cove *
</div>';
$mylink[10] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a shooting star over the aurora, Cabot Trail through Lake O'Law.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A shooting star over the aurora, Cabot Trail through Lake O'Law *
</div>';
$mylink[11] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a shooting star photobombing the milky way Doyles Road, Margaree Forks.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A shooting star photobombing the milky way Doyles Road, Margaree Forks *
</div>';
$mylink[12] = '<img src="https://www.capebretonstartpage.com/images/backgrounds/a small aurora at the end of the Margaree River.jpg">
<div class="description">
* A small aurora at the end of the Margaree River *
</div>';
//Change 3 to as many links you have added above
$id = rand(1,12);
echo $mylink[$id];
?>
```

Comment: General hint: Try to focus your question and examples on the necessary amount and the actual problem, for instance in ur example three array items with one containing `... through Lake O'Law ...` (the actual problem) would have been enough

Answer (score 0):

In PHP strings those literals can be escaped, e.g. `$value = 'What\'s up?';` (`\` used to escape literals)...

When outputting HTML, that should be encoded (e.g. `htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES)` is doing that in PHP) and would result in e.g. `<div class="description">What&#39;s up?</div>` (`&#39;` is the HTML entity representation for apostrophes)

**References**

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php